# Inline SVG Color - Color from the first appears on the second

Tags: svg

I'm just learing how to use Inline SVG's and I'm currently testing on JSFiddle.

I've found if I put 2 inline SVG's onto the same page the color from the first appears on the second. eg: if the first image has blue and the second image is grey the second image will appear blue.

Here is a single JSFiddle inline svg image that is grey: http://jsfiddle.net/txav2pve/

Here is a JSFiddle inline svg * 2 where the first image is blue and the second is the some grey image show above but it appears blue: http://jsfiddle.net/mmut46pt/

eg: here is the grey inline svg code:

```
<h1>Some sort of title</h1>

<p>How now brown cow. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="265.427px" height="105.59px" viewBox="0 0 265.427 105.59" enable-background="new 0 0 265.427 105.59"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Edit_Button_1_">
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="132.7144" y1="10.8496" x2="132.7144" y2="90.4107">
        <stop  offset="0.099" style="stop-color:#F5F6F6"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8267" style="stop-color:#E9E9E9"/>
    </linearGradient>

        <rect x="0.474" y="0.474" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#CDCCCC" stroke-width="0.9479" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="264.479" height="104.643"/>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="#6F6F6F" points="27.945,62.067 20.953,83.479 42.234,76.368                   "/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path fill="#6F6F6F" d="M67.206,22.81c3.765-3.827,9.988-3.805,14.024,0.166c4.024,3.969,4.154,10.186,0.39,14.013
                        L67.206,22.81z"/>
                </g>
                <polygon fill="#6F6F6F" points="45.999,72.609 31.698,58.312 62.865,27.153 77.16,41.45               "/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 100.8813 74.3232)" fill="#6F6F6F" font-family="'Verdana'" font-size="57.8802">EDIT</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm wondering how I can have multiple Inline SVG images on one page contained so the color doesn't bleed from inital images to later images?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both SVGs have a `<linearGradient>` element with `id="SVGID_1_"`.  `id` attributes are supposed to be unique on a page.  Different browsers handle clashing ids differently.  So your example works okay on Chrome, but is broken on FF.  In FF, your second SVG is using the gradient definition from the first SVG.

You need to make sure that no two SVGs, that are inlined on the same page, have duplicate ids.  You may need to hand edit one or more of your SVGs to achieve this.

So for example, [here is a version of your broken example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmut46pt/1/) that does work on FF:

To make it work, I changed the gradient in the second SVG from "SVGID_1_" to "SVGID_1_xxx".

Comment: thanks so much!! 100% understand now you have explained that and greatly appreciate your time... thanks again!